# multi join linq and group by year and month

Tags: c#, linq, join, group-by

I have the following linq queries and my aim is to group by  year and month and do some computations:  I have a ViewModel set up.  i am not even sure if my query will work as expected because it cant compile.  I get this error

```
System.NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233067
  Message=LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32] Range(Int32, Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
  Source=EntityFramework
```

Controller code

```
 public ActionResult Summary(int? yr, int? mn, int? BkId)
             {
                 var squery = SummaryYrMn(yr, mn, BkId);
                 return View(squery);
             }    

    public IEnumerable SummaryYrMn()
                 {
         var squery =
        (from bk in db.Books
        from year in Enumerable.Range(2010, DateTime.Today.Year)
        from month in Enumerable.Range(1, 12)
        let key = new { Year = year, Month = month }

        //sold books
        join tr in db.Transacts.Where(a => a.TransactTypeId==1 && a.Book.BookTypeId==1 ) on key
        equals new{tr.TransactDate.Year, tr.TransactDate.Month} into s

        //gifted books
        join tr2 in db.Transacts.Where(a => a.TransactTypeId == 2 && a.Book.BookTypeId == 1) on key
        equals new{tr2.TransactDate.Year, tr2.TransactDate.Month} into t

        //gifted  tracts books  book type = tract
      join tr3 in db.Transacts.Where(a => a.TransactTypeId == 2 && a.Book.BookTypeId == 2) on key
      equals new { tr3.TransactDate.Year, tr3.TransactDate.Month } into u

        select new SummaryViewModel
         {

      Year = year,
      Month = month,
      Gifted = (int?)t.Sum(c => c.TransactQty) ?? 0,
      GSales = (int?)s.Sum(c => c.TransactQty) ?? 0,
      GiftedTracts = (int?)u.Sum(c => c.TransactQty) ?? 0,
      TotalGift = ((int?)t.Sum(c => c.Book.BookPrice))*((int?)s.Sum(c => c.TransactQty)??0),
      TotalSale =   ((int?)s.Sum(c => c.TransactPrice))*((int?)s.Sum(c => c.TransactQty)??0)

       });

        return squery.AsEnumerable();
   }
```

Comment: Should that not be [System.Linq.Enumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable(v=vs.100).aspx)? Try fully-qualifying your Enumerable.Range().

Comment: Still not working with your suggestion.  Will you have done this in a different way?

Comment: Ah yes. I see. This is Linq to entities! Yes. Create a variable for each of your year and month, assign the Enumerable.Range into them. Then use those in your linq. EF is trying to generate sql from your linq and Enumerable.Range is not a sql function. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try starting the method SummaryYrMn like so...

```
var yrs = Enumerable.Range(2010, DateTime.Today.Year);
var months =  Enumerable.Range(1, 12);    
var squery =
        (from bk in db.Books
        from year in yrs
        from month in months
        let key = new { Year = year, Month = month }
...
```

The Enumarable.Range() is being translated into SQL by the Linq-to-Entities and does not exist in a sql context.